# Log get all properties in custom NLog Target

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, nlog

I have a custom made NLog `AsyncTaskTarget` target. At a first glance it seems to be working fine. I can log all messages within my custom Target class.

But, I would like to have structured logging. So I have setup my `nlog.config` like this within my `<target>`:

```xml
<layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
  <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
  <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
  <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
  <attribute name="Properties" encode="false" >
    <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true" excludeProperties="EventId_Id,EventId_Name,EventId" maxRecursionLimit="5"/>
  </attribute>
</layout>
```

Is there a way to also get the properties that are specified in the `attribute` tags within the log method?

For some reason the property values are alway null or empty.

```cs
protected override async Task WriteAsyncTask(IList<LogEventInfo> logEvents, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    foreach (var info in logEvents)
    {
        string logMessage = RenderLogEvent(Layout, info); // renders message
        var props = GetAllProperties(info); // count = 0
        var p = GetContextProperties(info); // = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the logger call.

Comment: @Julian Do you mean this: `_logger.LogInformation($"Test info: {DateTime.Now}");`? This is inside a Controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two features together. You have registered JsonLayout as target-Layout, so it will generate a Json-document for each LogEvent.

```
protected override async Task WriteAsyncTask(IList<LogEventInfo> logEvents, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    foreach (var info in logEvents)
    {
        string jsonDocument = RenderLogEvent(Layout, info); // Renders using JsonLayout
        var props = GetAllProperties(info);               // Renders properties
    }
}
```

You can configure your target to return properties when calling `GetAllProperties()`, but you have to enable it first like this:

```
<target type="MyFirst" name="first" includeEventProperties="true" includeMdlc="true">
  <contextproperty name="MachineName" layout="${machinename}" />
  <contextproperty name="ThreadId" layout="${threadid}" />
</target>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-async-target